# Unable to change the imageView by choosing a picture from the phone (Fragment)

Tags: image, android-studio, imageview, fragment

I've been looking for an answer for 2 days by looking and looking at many tutorials but I didn't find anything that helps me.

I'm having trouble with an ImageView. I would like to change the image by choosing a picture from my phone gallery. I'm using Android Studio.

I'd be so grateful if you guys can help me out to solve this issue. If you need any further information, do not hesitate to contact me.

Thanks in advance. Greetings from Switzerland.

```
public class AddCategory extends Fragment{

private static final int IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT = 1;
Button b;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addcategory, container, false);
    imageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_add);
    b = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i,IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT );
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER_SELECT && requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data){

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_add);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

}